# Issue with parsing nested JSON values with Lift-JSON

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

I'm using Scala 2.12 and trying to parse the below JSON file.

```
{
    "comp1": {
        "metrics": {
            "operation1": {
                "alias": "activity_operation",
                "weight": 10
            },
            "operation2": {
                "alias": "service_operation",
                "weight": 22
            }
        }
    },
    "comp2": {
        "metrics": {
            "operation1": {
                "alias": "activity_operation",
                "weight": 14
            },
            "operation4": {
                "alias": "service_operation",
                "weight": 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've loaded the json into config variable, defined a case class and trying the below:

```
  case class OperationDetails(alias: String, weight: Int)

  for (detail <- (config \ "comp1").children) {
    println(detail.extract[OperationDetails])
  }
```

This gives me the error `Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for alias. Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String`

I can't use `operation1' and retrieve children as operations are random.

I need to retrieve the operation names `operation1, operation2, operation4, ..` and their respective aliases and weights. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing at least one level of nesting, and possibly also the implicit val `formats`.

This will print all of the operations. Note the conversion into `JObject` in order to be able to retrieve field names.

```scala
  // Setup 
  case class Operation(alias: String, weight: Int)
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

  // Traversal
  val comps: List[JsonAST.JValue] = config.children
  for (comp <- comps) {
    val metrics:List[JsonAST.JValue] = comp.children
    for (metric <- metrics) {
      val operations:List[JsonAST.JField] = metric.asInstanceOf[JObject].obj
      for (operation <- operations) {
        val op = operation.value.extract[Operation]
        // Do something here
        println(s"${operation.name}:(${op.alias},${op.weight})")
      }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
operation1:(activity_operation,10)
operation2:(service_operation,22)
operation1:(activity_operation,14)
operation4:(service_operation,16)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm. I tried converting the JSON to Map using `asInstanceOf[JObject].values` and fetched the values from there, but that didn't look very elegant.